# изменить стиль другого элемента React JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Мне нужно изменить цвет блока с классом "strip" при клике на radio 
как это сделать ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super(props);
  }

  handleClick() {

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2 className="fade">Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="App-section">
          <div className="strip">
            <input type="radio" onClick={ this.handleClick } />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Точно при клике? Если да, то решение, например, такое:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      stripBg: ''
    };
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    this.setState({ stripBg: 'yellow' });
  }

  render() {
    const style = { backgroundColor: this.state.stripBg };
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2 className="fade">Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="App-section">
          <div className="strip" style={ style }>
            <input type="radio" onClick={ e => this.handleClick() } />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```